# Возможны ли race condition или visibility с локальными переменными?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть один экземпляр класса:

```
class A {

    public int f(int b) {
        int i = 1;
        return b + i;
    }

}
```

И два потока одновременно вызывают у этого экземпляра метод `f(int b)`. Возможны ли проблемы race condition или visibility с локальными переменными `i` и/или `b`? Или эти проблемы распространяются только на поля?

Comment: Локальные примитивы хранятся прямо на стэке треда, объекты - в куче, однако ссылки на эти объекты все равно находятся только на стэке, таким образом ко всему этому добру может получить доступ только создающий тред. Забегая вперед, в некоторых случаях JVM может для простоты вообще не создавать в таких местах объекты, заменяя это скаляризацией.

Comment: @etki если я правильно понимаю скаляризация не так уж часто встречается, нельзя же все на свете писать прямо на железе... Спасибо я понял что за локальные переменные можно не волноваться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Race condition имеет смысл только при работе с *разделяемыми* данными (ресурсами). В случае локальных переменных общего, разделяемого ресурса нет, так как каждый экземпляр функции имеет свой набор локальных переменных. Так что и race condition в этом случае невозможно.